# Is equation numbering in exported HTML considered deprecated for built in stylesheets?

Tags: export, html

TLDR or simply stated: how do I export equation/section numbers to HTML? The built-in function doesn't seem to do it.

Longer form of the question:
So I've been tinkering around with the built in stylesheets and the `Export` command and I've noticed that in principle equation numbering *should* work.

When you look at `PublicationDefault.nb` or `Notebook.nb` stylesheets you'll notice the use of the `IncludeCount` function, which looks like it should print a number into `'EquationNumberedLabel'` class of HTML code.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
Cell[StyleData["EquationNumbered", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Equation"]],
 ConversionRules:>{
  "HTML" -> {{"", ""}, {"<table class='EquationNumbered'><tr><td>", Automatic, 
  IncludeCount[
      "</td><td class='EquationNumberedLabel'>(`1`)</td></tr></table>", 
       "EquationNumbered"]}}}, ...]
```

I've tried exporting it with commands:

```
Export["test.html", SelectedNotebook[], "HTML"]
```

and

```
Export["test.html", SelectedNotebook[], "HTML", "MathOutput" -> "TeX"]
```

both don't seem to give me the equation numbers. Is this functionality really not intended to work?

**Edit:** You can also use the built in menu command from `File->Save`. It still doesn't render numbers. It doesn't even render se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears like this is not possible directly out of Mathematica.

If you have a document that consists purely of equations like this:

[image: eqs]

Then you can export to XML, then import the XML and modify the DOM, then export to HTML again.

First save to XML:

[image: save]

Then we need a method to insert this javascript into the doc:

```
function loadTags(){
    for(i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("p").length;i++) { 
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML = 
        document.getElementsByTagName("p")[i].innerHTML + 
            '<span style="position: absolute; right: 40px;">('+ i 
            +')</span>'};
 }
```

First read in the XML file as a string:

```
o = OpenRead["eqs.xml"]
h = ReadString[o]
Close[o]
```

This monstrosity is the escaped version of the above js with a script tag:

```
s = "<script> \nfunction loadTags(){\n\nfor(i=0; \
    i<document.getElementsByTagName(\"p\").length;i++) { \n\
    document.getElementsByTagName(\"p\")[i].innerHTML = \
    document.getElementsByTagName(\"p\")[i].innerHTML + '<span \
    style=\"position: absolute; right: 40px;\">(' + i + ')</span>'};\n\n}\
    \n\n\n</script>"
```

Mathematica is really good at finding things and inserting other things:

```
rules = {"<body" -> "<body onload=\"loadTags()\"", 
         "</body>" -> StringJoin["</body>", s]}
```

the `rules` will find the body start tag and call out custom js onload. they also find the ending body tag and insert our script.

then we write out or doctored XML file to HTML:

```
str = OpenWrite["numbered2.html"]
WriteString[str, StringReplace[h, rules]]
Close[str]
```

resulting in:

[image: result]

This model would need to adapt to different DOMs- like when other paragraph elements which shouldn't be numbered are present.

Comment: I really appreciate the input, at least we've got something that works! Thank you!